# ffmpeg won't convert GIF to WEBM

Tags: ffmpeg, gif, webm

I'm trying convert a GIF to a WEBM for uploads to my site, to get smaller files (GIFs are so big...) and get all the advantages of videos, like pausing.
But ffmpeg gives this error:

> ```
> Input #0, gif, from '1.gif':   Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
>     Stream #0:0: Video: gif, bgra, 960x540, 16.67 fps, 16.67 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (gif (native) ->
> vp8 (libvpx)) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help [libvpx @
> 0x5560ca413960] v1.6.1 [libvpx @ 0x5560ca413960] Transparency encoding
> with auto_alt_ref does not work Error initializing output stream 0:0
> -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
> Conversion failed!
> ```

Here's my ffmpeg line:

```
ffmpeg -r 16 -i 1.gif -c:v libvpx -crf 12 -b:v 500k test.webm
```

Comment: Add `-pix_fmt yuv420p`

Answer (score 13):

```
ffmpeg -y -i 1.gif -r 16 -c:v libvpx -quality good -cpu-used 0 -b:v 500K -crf 12 -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags faststart test.webm
```

Comment: I found `-pix_fmt yuv420p` to be the part that fixed the error.